# I want to make this using bootstrap 3, anyone help me how i start and divide it in columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[This is the website i want to make it using bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y55F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="logo col-md-2 pull-left">
                            <img src="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 pull-left">
                            Home
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 pull-left">
                            Hot Deals
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 pull-left">
                            Products
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 pull-left">
                            About
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 pull-left">
                            Contact
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right img-icons">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                icon1
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                icon2
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                icon3
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This rough structure of bootstrap . Hope this would be helpfull